# Laravel relation total count

Tags: laravel, count, relation

I have a `Category` model and a `Description` model.

When displaying my categories in a list, I also want to include a total number of related descriptions for all categories, but without having to load all the descriptions itself.

Using withCount works on each seperate category object:

```
auth()->user()->categories()->withCount('descriptions')->get()
```

So the above returns all categories and adds a `descriptions_count` value in the object, which is not what I want.

I just want one number of total descriptions for all categories. Any easy, simple wat to achieve this, without having to eager load the descriptions itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a query with `whereHas()`:

```
Description::whereHas('category', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', \Auth::id());
})->count();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, I always forget about whereHas. And just now I realized I could've just grabbed the count of all active descriptions for a user, since they are always linked to a category anyway. Doh :)

Comment: Yes, you probably could have a `hasManyThrough` relationship on your user model for all the descriptions, through categories. This way you'd have the same result even shorter.